# Why does https://login.microsoftonline.com/... login page shows GUID instead of user email?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Microsoft azure Active directory B2c to authenticate our website. we follow the model given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-dotnet) to authenticate our website. The authentication flow is as follows

1. I click signin button(in our site) to login(login page redirects the user to microsoft online login page)
2. I am redirected to microsoft login page https://login.microsoftonline.com/ with all the custom values like tanent id, etc.
3. I enter the user name and password to login.
   ......
4. I click logout at the end, I am logged out of the site.

Next time when I login, the flow is as follows

1. I click login button(from our site)
2. I am redirected to the microsoft login page.
3. Microsoft Login page remebers my email as I already logged-in once
4. I clicke my email
5. I am redirected to a login page, where I enter username(email) and password

It works fine most of the times. But sometimes microsoft login page shows GUID instead of my user email id on its login page. Is there a reason why the login page shows GUID instead of email and how to avoid this? Following is the screen short that shows GUID instead of email

[image]

Comment: Did this issue only occur for the specific application or all the applications integrate with Azure AD? For example, could you reproduce this issue when you sign in the account directly with this [link](https://login.microsoftonline.com/)?

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT We just try with one application. We can't reproduce it when we use the direct link.

Comment: The B2C application a litter different with the normal, please check the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet) to build the application with B2C tenant.  I am also failed to reproduce this issue using the code sample from [here](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet.git).